# Find table from querying column name in oracle SQL developer

Tags: php, sql, oracle, coldfusion, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to query a database for a column name to find the table without knowing the table name (there are a huge number of tables)

I am working with a huge database at the moment and trying to find where, based on CFML code and the URL of the problematic page, a website is retrieving information from. I am new to ColdFusion however I can see that the URL contains a few ID references with column names. Some I have been able to find easily and others, I have no idea as the column names are quite vague e.g. 'NTASKID'.

My plan is to try to query the database using the column name but Google has presented me queries which require knowing the table name which I do not have. I guess those examples may have been more useful for denormalised tables(?).

If someone knows such a query it would be great. Additionally, could someone please comment on whether I am going down the right avenue of investigation here?

Comment: try `select * from ALL_TABLES`

Comment: just to be clear do you mean something like: SELECT * FROM database_name where column like '%task%';

Comment: I am not very fit in Oracle, but Oracle should contain a table `ALL_TABLES` that holds informations about your tables

Comment: Does the cfml code have sql inside a cfquery tag?

Comment: They are a bit more difficult at the moment because I am learning cfml as I go along but I am also investigating this right now, cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The query that worked was

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%TASK%' 
AND owner = 'database_name';
```

It was the 'owner' part I did not previously know about. Everyone who answered certainly opened avenues for further Googling.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find table name then 'juergen d' answered your question. If you nee to find column names then use user_tab_columns/all_tab_columns to select column names where table='YOUR_TABLE' - must be in upper case as well as column names.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE itself has a feature for this, View > Find DB Obect

here's [a 20 second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1S3BjLc4tQ&list=UUdzrhKSHU3Tf8QDOuM7EF9g) showing it, in action